# Excel finding blanks cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have tried using the GUI and VBA to find and fill in blanks.

Unfortunately, both do not find the last set of blanks.

Example:

[image: Example]

If I highlight cells 1 through 20, and use the GUI ( Find -> Goto -> Blanks....) 
it only highlights items above the done line. Similar with this code

```
With Range("B1:B20").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
```

If I highlight from 17 to 20, and use the GUI, it does find/highlight the last blank cells. The cells **do not** contain data ( I have checked ). What can I get to get Excel to not stop at line 17

Thanks

Comment: Look like Excel will limit itself to the used range, typing something (anything) in line 21 will extend it. and the blank cells in rows 18-20 should now be filled in

Comment: Yes, it appears that it does limit itself to "used rows", which is strange because it says it will find all instances in the Range object you give it. Back to cell by cell , like below.

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple code:

```
Sub HighlightBlanks1()
    Dim c
    For Each c In Range("B1:B20")
        If IsEmpty(c) Then
            c.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Next
End Sub
'or using your approach
Sub HighlightBlanks2()
    Range("B1:B20").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, that is the code I used to tell that the cells were in fact blank. However, I was trying to use specialcells as it will work on a range all at once, and it is supposed to be faster that cell by cell.